# package.json dependencies for firebase

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, ibm-cloud

Hey I am new to bluemix. 
I wanted to create a webapp that stores info in firebase. However I realized I couldnt run 'npm install' on bluemix. I was told to update the package.json files of my app.

For firebase what do I have to write in the package.json to get it working?

Comment: If Bluemix runs regular nodejs, then you'd add a dependency for `"firebase": "2.x.x"`.

Answer (score 3):

The [Node.js runtime on Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/sdk-for-nodejs/) allows you to execute your Node.js applications as you would do on your local environment. To add a dependency to your application you simply have to add a line to your package.json file in the *dependencies* attribute, e.g.:

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase": "^2.4.2"
}
```

Now when you push the application on Bluemix the buildpack will retrieve all the required dependencies and add them to the *node_modules* folder.

Then firebase will be available to use, you have just to require it:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
```